# Can all elements of a reduced residue class of a primorial $p$ be expressed as a simple equation in terms of the factors of the primorial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primorial, reduced-residue-system

I've noticed that for the smaller primes, it is possible to state each element of its reduced residue class as a simple equation in terms of the factors of the primorial.

For example, consider the primorial $5\# = 30$

The reduced residue class is $\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$

Each of these elements can be expressed as a simple equation in terms of the factors of the primorial.

- 1 = $\frac{30}{5} - 5$
- 7 = $\frac{30}{3} - 3$
- 11 = $\frac{30}{5} + 5$
- 13 = $\frac{30}{2} - 2$
- 17 = $\frac{30}{2} + 2$
- 19 = $\frac{30}{2} + 2*2$
- 23 = $\frac{30}{2} + 2*2*2$
- 29 = $30 - 1$

Is this always the case?  Is there a point where this stops being true?

Comment: This may depend a lot on what you consider to be "a simple equation".

Comment: By "simple", I meant something like this: $\frac{a}{b} + c$ where $a,b,c$ are all expressible solely in terms of factors of $p\#$.

Comment: Now it depends on what you mean by "expressible solely in terms of factors of $p\#$".

Comment: By "expressible solely in terms of factors $p\#$", I just meant that each $a,b,c$ is in the form of $f_i^{n_i}*f_{i+1}^{n_{i+1}}*\cdots$ and each $f_i | p\#$.

Comment: @LarryFreeman Is there a reason you don't just say $a \pm b$, where $a$ and $b$ only have prime factors dividing $n\#$? Or do you want (your) $a/b$ to be square-free?

Comment: Hi Matthew, As you point out, I mean $a \pm b$ where $a$ and $b$ have only prime factors dividing $n\#$.  I used $\frac{a}{b}$ solely because I wanted to make it as clear as possible that $\frac{30}{2} + 2$ could not be divisible by $2, 3,$ or $5$.